# Sorting a resultset during the iteration over them

Tags: groovy

Given is a xml File with following content

```
<ROOT>
  <Group Name="Database"> 
     <User Name="Thorsten"/>
     <User Name="Karl"/>
     <User Name="Beate"/>
     <User Name="Heinz"/>
     <User Name="Andreas"/>
  </Group>
</ROOT>
```

now i can read it with an groovy script something like this

```
def out = "";
def result = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("D:\\User.xml"));
result.Group.User.each {
out += it.@Name.text()+ '\n';
}
println out;
```

the output is in the order they appear in the XML file

```
Thorsten
Karl
Beate
Heinz
Andreas
```

is it possible to sort, in alphabetic order, the resultset during the iteration over them?

Georg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*During* the iteration? Of course not.

But if you use `XmlParser`, you could do this:

```
def doc = new XmlParser().parse(new File("users.xml"));
foo = doc.Group.User.sort { it.@Name }.collect { it.@Name }.join("\n")
println foo
```

Which outputs:

```
Andreas
Beate
Heinz
Karl
Thorsten
```

Comment: Thank you, that's even shorter than I thought and hands me completely